# Knockout computed vs. subscription, timing issues

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just found out, that in KnockoutJS subscription functions are evaluated before dependent computables and need someone who can commit that, because I can't find anything about Knockouts timing in the docs or discussion forums.

That means: If I have a model like this...

```
var itemModel = function (i) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(i.Id);
    self.Title = ko.observable(i.Title);
    self.State = ko.observable(i.State);

};

var appModel = function () {
   var self = this;

   self.Items = ko.observableArray() // <-- some code initializes an Array of itemModels here
   self.indexOfSelectedItem = ko.observable();

   self.selectedItem = ko.computed(function () {
       if (self.indexOfSelectedItem() === undefined) {
            return null;
       }
       return self.Items()[self.indexOfSelectedItem()];
   });
};
```

where I want to keep track of the selected array item with an observable index field, and I subscribe to this index field like this...

```
appModel.indexOfSelectedItem.subscribe(function () {
    // Do something with appModel.selectedItem()
    alert(ko.toJSON(appModel.selectedItem()));
}
```

...the subscription function is evaluated before the computed is reevaluated with the new index value, so I will get the selectedItem() that corresponds to the last selected Index and not the actual selected Index.

Two questions:

- Is that right?
- Then why should I make use of ko.computed() if a simple function gets me the current selected Item every time I call it, while ko.computed gets evaluated at anytime where everything is done already and I dont need it anymore?

Comment: Why don't you subscibe on the selectedItem? So `appModel.selectedItem.subscribe(function () {` in this case your function will be called when the `selectedItem` will change. By the way there is an error in your computed:  `return self.Items[self.indexOfSelectedItem()];` should be  `return self.Items()[self.indexOfSelectedItem()];` note the extra `()`

Comment: Because there is not only one computed which depends on the index, but some more. I need a handler where I can update a lot of things in my UI and where all these computed fields are updated already then as well. Which one should I subscribe now? I thought of a computed being like a getter function, that is evaluated when I call it. In fact there is a portion of time, where these are bound to an older value, so I think its better to go with simple getter functions then, isn't it? Thanks you are right about the extra ()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all computeds in Knockout are evaluated in an eager fashion, not lazily (i.e., *not* when you first access them).

As soon as one dependency changes, all all subscriptions are notified and all connected computeds are re-evaluated. You can change that behavior to "lazy" by specifying [the `deferEvaluation` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#computed_observable_reference) in a computed observable, but you cannot do this for a subscription.

Hoewever, I think there is no need to depend on the index of the selected item. In fact, that's even bad design because you are not *really* intested in the numerical value of the index, but rather in the item it represents.

You could reverse the dependencies by creating a writeable computed observable that gives you the index of the currently selected item (for diplay purposes) and allows to change it as well (for convenience).

```
function AppModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Items = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.indexOfSelectedItem = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var i,
                allItems = self.Items(),
                selectedItem = self.selectedItem();

            for (i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
                if (allItems[i] === selectedItem) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        },
        write: function (i) {
            var allItems = self.Items();

            self.selectedItem(allItems[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Knockout favors storing/handling the actual values instead of just indexes to values, so it would probably not be difficult to make the necessary changes to your view. Just make everything that previously wrote to `indexOfSelectedItem` now write to `selectedItem` directly. Dependencies on `selectedItem` will continue to work normally.

In a well-designed Knockout application you will rarely ever have the need to handle the index of an array item. I'd recommend removing the `write` part of the computed once everything works.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4hLLn/

Comment: Thanks, thats really a great and helpful suggestion (actually I don't know much about how to design a knockout app well). I will do it this way. I also need the index to be writeable, because I bind the Items to a jquery ui accordion where the accordion panels correspond to the array indices. So if I click onto a accordion panel to select the item, I haven't found a better way to select it except setting appModel.indexOfSelectedItem() to the panels index in the accordion (the panels are not aware of the KO model classes). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think there is. I'll try to come up with a fiddle for that, hang on.

Comment: The key point is to separate view, model and binding from each other. The cleanest way is to make the accordion a property of the binding declaration. For example you could state the intent *"This element should display as an accordion and the currently active panel should be associated to the selected item"*. Since Knockout does not know about accordions, you can create a custom binding for that, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/4hLLn/1/. *(Disclaimer: This is an example. More complete custom bindings for jQuery UI widgets have been created by others, have a look around.)*

Comment: Ah, well. For some reason the fiddle refuses to run in IE. Seems to be jsFiddle-specific, though. Firefox and Chrome work fine.

Comment: Yes, I got the key point, and I also implemented a custom binding for the Items to accordion bind. To be honest I just googled for "Knockout custom binding jquery accordion" and took the best solution which worked for me and displayed the items as I also filter them, but I do not really understand what and how the update-handler does (when is it executed? in Which context?) and how I can set the selected Item with it. But your Fiddle is way more sophisticated than the last example I've seen for this. I'll go and investigate this stuff a little bit more. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Here is a little extension: http://jsfiddle.net/4hLLn/2/ It allows you to dynamically bind the accorion options (like, `'disabled'`) to your view model.

Comment: After stepping through the code: Did't know that I can associate the complete Item with ko.dataFor() with the panel and get this back again when selecting it.... thats really cool. Wisdom rises, Thanks again!

Comment: The `init` handler is called once, when the element that contains the binding is first encountered/handled by Knockout. Use it to set up any basic stuff you need to do once (like, creating the accordion on it). The `update` handler is called when the underlying observables that you refer to in the binding change. It actually is subject to the subscription and dependency tracking mechanism in Knockout. You should read the documentation page on custom binding handlers.

Comment: Yes, you can use `ko.dataFor()` (and `ko.contextFor()`, to get the binding context), but you should constrain that to binding handlers. Don't use it in the view model, because the view model must not know anything about the elements that display it. (*Any* DOM interaction in the view model – be it jQuery or `ko.dataFor(element)` – is an indicator of a badly designed or missing binding handler.)